# why could not access the uvicorn service port when deploy the app in docker

Tags: python-3.x, docker, fastapi

After I deploy my app with docker container, using this command in the docker container shows error:

```
~/chat-server # curl http://127.0.0.1:8000
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8000 after 0 ms: Connection refused
```

this is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.10-alpine3.16

LABEL jiang (jigtigqi@gmail.com)

ENV LANG=en_US.UTF-8 \
    LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 \
    TZ=Asia/Shanghai

RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime \
    && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone \
    && mkdir -p /root/chat-server 

# upgrade pip
RUN pip install --upgrade pip && apk add curl

ADD . /root/chat-server/

EXPOSE 8000

RUN pip3 install -r /root/chat-server/requirements.txt
WORKDIR /root/chat-server/
ENTRYPOINT exec python3 -m uvicorn main:app --port 8000 --host 0.0.0.0 --reload
```

and this is the main.py:

```
from typing import Union

from fastapi import FastAPI

from src.chat.chatgpt import chat_server

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/")
def read_root():
    return {"Hello": "World"}
```

this works fine with my local machine, could not access the service after deploy into kubernetes cluster even through request from the cluster's container. Am I missing something? I have tried add `--host 0.0.0.0` but still could not work. This is the ps command from container:

```
~/chat-server # ps
PID   USER     TIME  COMMAND
    1 root      0:07 python3 -m uvicorn main:app --port 8000 --host 0.0.0.0 --reload
    7 root      0:00 [python3]
    8 root      0:00 [python3]
    9 root      0:00 sh
   35 root      0:00 ps
```

this is the log of kubenretes pod:

```
➜  ~ kubectl logs chat-server-service-599b95f4cd-5rnvb --tail=100
INFO:     Will watch for changes in these directories: ['/root/chat-server']
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://0.0.0.0:8000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
INFO:     Started reloader process [1] using StatReload
```

this is my deployment configuration:

```
➜  ~ kubectl get deployments chat-server-service -o yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: "16"
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
      {"apiVersion":"apps/v1","kind":"Deployment","metadata":{"annotations":{},"labels":{"app":"chat-server-service"},"name":"chat-server-service","namespace":"reddwarf-pro"},"spec":{"progressDeadlineSeconds":600,"replicas":1,"revisionHistoryLimit":10,"selector":{"matchLabels":{"app":"chat-server-service"}},"strategy":{"rollingUpdate":{"maxSurge":"25%","maxUnavailable":"25%"},"type":"RollingUpdate"},"template":{"metadata":{"annotations":{"kubectl.kubernetes.io/restartedAt":"2022-06-15T13:12:33Z"},"creationTimestamp":null,"labels":{"app":"chat-server-service"}},"spec":{"containers":[{"env":[{"name":"DATABASE_URL","valueFrom":{"configMapKeyRef":{"key":"database_url","name":"fortune-service-pro-config"}}},{"name":"MUSIC_DATABASE_URL","valueFrom":{"configMapKeyRef":{"key":"music_database_url","name":"fortune-service-pro-config"}}},{"name":"QUARK_DATABASE_URL","valueFrom":{"configMapKeyRef":{"key":"quark_database_url","name":"fortune-service-pro-config"}}},{"name":"DICT_DATABASE_URL","valueFrom":{"configMapKeyRef":{"key":"dict_database_url","name":"fortune-service-pro-config"}}},{"name":"FORTUNE_DATABASE_URL","valueFrom":{"configMapKeyRef":{"key":"fortune_database_url","name":"fortune-service-pro-config"}}},{"name":"ENV","valueFrom":{"configMapKeyRef":{"key":"env","name":"fortune-service-pro-config"}}}],"image":"registry.cn-hongkong.aliyuncs.com/reddwarf-pro/chat-server:c51608efaa8c11b5d3c475399550180068a107f1","imagePullPolicy":"IfNotPresent","name":"fortune-service","ports":[{"containerPort":80,"protocol":"TCP"}],"resources":{"limits":{"cpu":"50m","memory":"20Mi"},"requests":{"cpu":"20m","memory":"6Mi"}},"terminationMessagePath":"/dev/termination-log","terminationMessagePolicy":"File"}],"dnsPolicy":"ClusterFirst","imagePullSecrets":[{"name":"hongkong-regcred"}],"restartPolicy":"Always","schedulerName":"default-scheduler","securityContext":{},"terminationGracePeriodSeconds":30}}}}
    kubernetes.io/change-cause: kubectl set image deployment/chat-server-service chat-server-service=registry.cn-hongkong.aliyuncs.com/reddwarf-pro/chat-server:f4d5b0ccb8b4c0e5cfd37546ef5cdcb9aabfd67a
      --record=true --namespace=reddwarf-pro
  creationTimestamp: "2023-03-02T09:49:51Z"
  generation: 21
  labels:
    app: chat-server-service
  name: chat-server-service
  namespace: reddwarf-pro
  resourceVersion: "111857114"
  uid: 275da678-95ad-419c-816b-74f08298116f
spec:
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 600
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: chat-server-service
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 25%
      maxUnavailable: 25%
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        kubectl.kubernetes.io/restartedAt: "2023-03-02T12:18:14Z"
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: chat-server-service
    spec:
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: DATABASE_URL
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
              key: database_url
              name: fortune-service-pro-config
        - name: MUSIC_DATABASE_URL
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
              key: music_database_url
              name: fortune-service-pro-config
        - name: QUARK_DATABASE_URL
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
              key: quark_database_url
              name: fortune-service-pro-config
        - name: DICT_DATABASE_URL
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
              key: dict_database_url
              name: fortune-service-pro-config
        - name: FORTUNE_DATABASE_URL
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
              key: fortune_database_url
              name: fortune-service-pro-config
        - name: ENV
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
              key: env
              name: fortune-service-pro-config
        image: registry.cn-hongkong.aliyuncs.com/reddwarf-pro/chat-server:f4d5b0ccb8b4c0e5cfd37546ef5cdcb9aabfd67a
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: chat-server-service
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          protocol: TCP
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 50m
            memory: 20Mi
          requests:
            cpu: 20m
            memory: 6Mi
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        terminationMessagePolicy: File
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: hongkong-regcred
      restartPolicy: Always
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      securityContext: {}
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
status:
  availableReplicas: 1
  conditions:
  - lastTransitionTime: "2023-03-15T07:28:38Z"
    lastUpdateTime: "2023-03-15T07:28:38Z"
    message: Deployment has minimum availability.
    reason: MinimumReplicasAvailable
    status: "True"
    type: Available
  - lastTransitionTime: "2023-03-02T12:38:52Z"
    lastUpdateTime: "2023-03-15T07:45:24Z"
    message: ReplicaSet "chat-server-service-599b95f4cd" has successfully progressed.
    reason: NewReplicaSetAvailable
    status: "True"
    type: Progressing
  observedGeneration: 21
  readyReplicas: 1
  replicas: 1
  updatedReplicas: 1
```

this is the netstat command output:

```
~/chat-server # netstat -tulpen
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
```

I want the server side to return hello world when using curl like this:

```
➜  ~ curl localhost:8000
{"Hello":"World"}
```

Comment: can you add some additional details for Kubernetes deployment? have you created a NodePort for port exposing?

Comment: I using the curl command in the kubernetes pod, it did not works in itself pod. @George

Comment: What does `netstat -tulpen` say in pod?

Comment: `~/chat-server # netstat -tulpen
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name` @tarle

Comment: I need the command works like this: `➜  ~ curl localhost:8000
{"Hello":"World"}` @TheFool

Comment: Very strange that if python3 runs and bind to 8000 properly, netstat shall output something like: `tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      37/python3`.

Comment: I have already login into the pod using k9s tool and run the command in the pod. @TheFool

Comment: So what is the issue that cause the pod did not how the binding pods like this? I am confusing by this problem for a day. @tarle

Comment: Does the image work in plain Docker, without Kubernetes?  Can you access it from other Pods via a Service?  Especially in Kubernetes I'd use `kubectl exec` shells only sparingly, and wouldn't especially worry about things working differently in that context if they work elsewhere.

Comment: it works fine with my local machine docker container, then I guess maybe the traefik listening on the host 8000 that cause this issue, then I changed the port from 8000 to 8001, still could not work in remote kubernetes pod. @DavidMaze confusing....

Comment: Is your pod frozen at the log message "Started reloader process [1] using StatReload", without displaying any further log messages?